# How do I print a certain sentence from a file?

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to print a certain sentence from an external file in python. The file is a .log file.

This is how the file written:

```
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties
[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 7
```

I want to print everything in the first [ ] and everything after [notice] or [error].
I think I need to use the `split` command but I don't know how.

Comment: A good way to learn about how to use a command is read the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import re

with open('logfile.log') as logfile:
    for line in map(str.strip, logfile):
        m = re.findall('\[.*?\]', line)
        if len(m) > 1 and m[1] in ('[notice]', '[error]'):
            offset = line.find(m[1]) + len(m[1]) + 1
            print(m[0], line[offset:])
```

**Note:**

There are no validity checks here. If a line in the log file doesn't exactly match the format shown in the question, this could fail

Comment: Thanks, this was exacly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, but probably it won't be the fastest way...

```
text = ['[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [notice] workerEnv.init() ok /etc/httpd/conf/workers2.properties',
        '[Mon Dec 05 14:01:48 2005] [error] mod_jk child workerEnv in error state 7']

for line in text:
    kw = '[notice]' if line.find('[notice]') >= 0 else '[error]' if line.find('[error]') >= 0 else None
    # Filter out every line which does not contain '[notice]' or '[error]'
    if kw:
        tmp = line.split(kw)
        # [1:-2] is needed to get rid of the '[' and ']'
        print(tmp[0][1:-2], tmp[1])
```